# Concurrent connections for Teradata using concurrent.future

Tags: python-3.x, teradata, concurrent.futures

I am trying to download data using Python from TeraData but the current process runs for 12hours because of the complex SQL joins. I have tried to use concurrent.futures but I get an error "A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending." I am new to this and still trying to figure it out.  python 3.7

```
  import pyodbc 
  import pandas as pd
  from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

   def chunker(seq, size):
         return (seq[pos:pos + size] for pos in range(0, len(seq), size))


  def task():


      for group in chunker(fDocNum3, 10):  #fDocNum3 consists of data which I break into chuncks to use as input for SQL query


    dataList = ""

    dfToList = group['Column_name'].tolist()
    for i in dfToList:
           dataList += "'"+i+ "'" + ","
    dataList=dataList[0:-1]

    try:
        DataSet1= pd.read_sql(("SOME COMPLEX QUERY where column in ( "+ 
        dataList + ")",TDconn) #EDIT .. i hope this makes more sense. 


        return DataSet1

    except:
        dfToListEx = dfToListEx.append(dfToList, ignore_index=True)
        continue


   def main():
     DataSet1 = pd.DataFrame() 
     #executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4)
   with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
        future = executor.submit(task)
        fDataSet = fDataSet.append(DataSet1, ignore_index=True) 
   #print(future.done())
   print(future.result())


   if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Comment: Twelve hours until the first row is returned or the last row is returned? If it is the former, what can be done to improve the query? Twelve hours of elapsed time before first row on Teradata is excessive.

Comment: 12 hours till the last chunk of 10 is retrieved. What I mean is , if  the dataframe "fDocNum3" has 75000 rows then 7500 iteration of _chunker_ is run which is of 10 each. The reason why I had to make chunks of 10 was if I used anymore then I would get spool error in Teradata.

Comment: That means you run 7500 queries against Teradata, average runtime 6 seconds per query. If you run out of spool this means either you don't have enough spool (try to talk to your DBA to get more) or your query is either very complex or badly written. Can you show the query and the Explain?